# Get Last Javascript Error

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a bug reporter for my app.  When something goes wrong, the user fills out a form and describes the problem and this is sent to the server.  As part of the data collected in this form, I'd like to include the last javascript error.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: you could insert your whole code in a try/catch block, which would catch everything that failed and didn't get catched before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could implement a function to capture errors by using `window.onerror` ([MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onerror)). That way the last error could be stored in `window.localStorage` or wherever you want and you could retrieve it again, when the bug report is filled.

Comment: What's the browser support for window.localStorage like?  I need to minimally support IE 8.

Answer (score 7):

you can use `window.onerror`

```
window.onerror = function(error, url, line) {
    //save errors here
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can assign a function to [`window.onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onerror) and store the error information from the arguments.

Comment: How to make this work in chrome `var errors = [];
window.onerror = function(){
    errors.push(arguments);
}; throw new Error("asd")` Or does it only work for "real" errors? Edit: doesn't work for `ReferenceErrors` either